# Python library for Kafka message queue - For sending the request (client side) and reply the response back (Server side)

Tags: python, apache-kafka

Need a proper python library for Kafka message queue - client side and server side samples as well in python.

**On Client side programing using python program: Below are the action items**

1. Required to connect Kafka message queue.
2. Send the user request to Kafka.

**On Server side programing using python program: Below are the action items**

1. Required to connect Kafka message queue.
2. Process the request generated by the client side.
3. Respond back the result to client.

Comment: Do you mean Kafka or TIBCO EMS ? Your question is not clear

Comment: Voting to close for looking for software recommendations. Refer [help] for what is on-topic

Comment: Need a python library to connect the message queue. Both client side scripting  (to send the request to message queue) and server side scripting (to process the request sent by the client) as well.

Comment: Need a python library to connect the message queue. Both client side scripting  (to send the request to message queue) and server side scripting (to process the request sent by the client) as well.

(1) Instead of kafka or Tibco  - I need a generic Python API to connect to message queue to achieve both client side and server side scripting. i.e. Message queue may be either Tibco EMS to kafka. 

(2) If #1 is not possible i.e. If Python does not have generic module for Message queue mechanism. Share the standard python API for connecting both Tibco and Kafka message queue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be all included in kafka-python of version 2.0.2. See [kafka-python documentation](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/). I am using it for a small service, which pulls messages from Kafka-Brokers, create an ancient SOAP Webservice request and receive some interesting data from a huge database. Then I push a message into another topic afterwards, which gets consumed by another backend and is forwarded to a Webapp GUI.

I am not sure, what you expect. Couldn't you find a lib, and if, why not?

Comment: My choice of message queue is not been finalized whether to use Kafka or Tibco EMS or Solace. 
So i need a python API to access message queue which should be queue independent (brand independent), right now we are using Tibco EMS (C++ coding). 
Even though my message queue will change in future, my python code should not get affected.
If any such module is available, i can use that to start my coding and  access the tibco ems for now to test (client side  and server side action) using the generic message queue independent API in python.
Like DBI module we have in Perl programming.

Comment: Okay. I've never heard of Tibco. I'm also not sure, if there exists a mq agnostic lib. AND a mq is a integral architectural decision. Many side effects have to be taken into account when changing it. This shouldn't be taken lightly.